# Remove directories / sub-directories when path could be any of 50 using PowerShell 5 or >

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Remove directories / sub-directories when path could be any of 50 using PowerShell 5 or >.

Remove `livebolivar.com` and it's sub-directories from `any of 50 folders named mmddyy`

```
"%USERPROFILE%\desktop\websites\"any of 50 folders named mmddyy"\livebolivar.com"
```

Remove %USERPROFILE%\desktop\websites\011920\livebolivar.com

Finds too much:

```
gci %USERPROFILE%\desktop\websites -recurse | Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer)} | Foreach { if ( $_.Name -eq "livebolivar.com") {remove-item $_.fullname -confirm}}
```

Did not work:

```
gci -exclude favorites %USERPROFILE%\desktop\websites -recurse | Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer)} | Foreach { if ( $_.Name -eq "livebolivar.com") {remove-item $_.fullname -confirm}}
```

This deleted the subfolders:

```
$path= @("%USERPROFILE%\desktop\websites\*\livebolivar.com")
$folders= gci -path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer} |Group-Object {$_.FullName.Split('_')[0] }
ForEach($folder in $folders){
$folder.Group | % { Remove-Item $_.fullname -recurse -force}}
```

Make test folders:

```
pushd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
foreach($i in -10..-1){
$z=(Get-Date).AddDays($i).tostring("MMddyy")
ni -itemtype directory $z\livebolivar.com\New Folder > $null}
ni -itemtype file $z\livebolivar.com\New Folder\test.txt > $null}
popd 
exit
```

Recurse directories remove directories recursively remove directories and sub-directories with remove-item remove directories and sub-directories with ri

Comment: It's hard to make sense of your question. What is the folder structure? Where would you use a wildcard? Does this return the folders you want to delete: `gci "$Home\Desktop\Websites" -dir -recurse | ? Name -like 'livebolivar.com'`?

Comment: Is checking for a six-digit parent folder close enough? `gci "$Home\Desktop\Websites" -dir -recurse | ? { ($_.Name -like 'livebolivar.com') -and ($_.Parent.Name -match '\d{6}')}`

Comment: So they all have six-digit parent folders. If they don't you need to edit you question providiing explicit examples of what is being included that shouldn't be.

Comment: What paths were returned by the last query that weren't valid???

Comment: I did not understand your comments. I plugged your `gci` into my remove-item command and your `gci` works.

Comment: It's quite rude to remove your comments & make it look like I'm talking to myself. Did I miss a "Thank you"???

Comment: If you want anything post an answer. The question asked for remove. You only provided find.

Comment: [Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7). "Teach a man to fish..."

Comment: [About Pipelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Recursively remove directory with wildcard.

```
gci $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\websites\*\livebolivar.com | % {ri $_.fullname -recurse -force -whatif}
```

% Performs an operation against each item in a collection of input objects.

$_ represents the current item from the pipe.

.fullname is path\name.ext

No sub-directories? `-force` is not needed

```
gci $env:USERPROFILE\desktop\websites\*\livebolivar.com | % {ri $_.fullname -recurse -whatif}
```